# Error while downloading a file from a folder in dropbox

Tags: android, filesystems, dropbox-api

Following is the code snippet I'm using to download a file from dropbox. I'm testing on a marshmallow device and I have added the code to ask permission during the runtime.

```
public void getIt(View v){
   DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/DropBoxIntegration_CRUD_Android-master");
    String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, accessToken);
    try {
        DbxDownloader<FileMetadata> downloader = client.files().download("/test/pic.jpg");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/pic.jpg");
        downloader.download(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (DbxException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch ( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
05-14 12:46:35.141 12456-12456/app.dropboxapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /pic.jpg: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Even after adding the permission, its saying that its a read only file system.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> new FileOutputStream("/pic.jpg");

FileOutputStream expects a full path.

Change to

```
new OpenFileOutput("pic.jpg");
```

And you do not need any permission for this storage location.